# Laravel Create Method Syntax Alternative

Tags: php, laravel, syntax, laravel-8

I'm building relationships between the users and posts tables. I'm wondering if there is a way to write this differently than this syntax?

```
$request->user()->posts()->create([
  'body' => $request->body
]);
```

Using syntax like this below how can achieve the same result as above?

```
Post::create([
  'body' => $request->body,
]);
```

I'm curious because I like to keep the same patterns.

Comment: you would add the `user_id` field to that array (which would have to be fillable on the model) ... i would suggest using the first method and let eloquent handle the needed key for the relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
Post::create([
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
    'body' => $request->body,
]);
```

But for relations it's best to do your first solution.